# Replace method takes a least two arguments

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My python code returns the following error.

```
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This is the line that is causing this error, it basically removes the comma, replaces it with a dot and turns it into a float

```
v=str.replace(',', '.').astype('float')
```

Before I had the following line, which worked fine but it misses the conversion to float part

```
v=v.replace(',', '.')
```

Comment: v=float(str.replace(',', '.')) try these

Comment: You forgot about the `Series`  `v`: `v.str.replace(',', '.').astype('float')`

Comment: @Mykola Zotko  If I am trying ```v=v.str.replace(',','.').astype('float')```, still geting an error ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'```

Answer (score 1):

Well it is unclear what is `v` in your question? , but given the error, I can guess it is a string, which you need to convert to float

so you need to do following:

```
v='5,458'
v=float(v.replace(',','.'))
print(v)
print(type(v))
```

**Output**

```
5.458
<class 'float'>
```

the line causing the error in your case is wrong, as it is used for pandas columns  conversionand if `v` is supposed to be a pandas columns you need to make sure it hold data as such:

```
a=['45,48','4,56','45,7','67,5']
df=pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A'])
df
```

**Output**

```
    A
0   45,48
1   4,56
2   45,7
3   67,5
```

```
v=df['A']
v.dtypes
```

**Output**

```
dtype('O')
```

then do the conversion

```
v=v.str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
v
```

**Output**

```
0    45.48
1     4.56
2    45.70
3    67.50
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the exact code steps you do; because in this code
`v=str.replace(',', '.').astype('float')` why are you replacing str??

Below scenario worked for me

```
v = "22,23"
v = float(v.replace(",","."))
print(v)
```

Output is:`22.23`

```
type(v)
class 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
`v.str.replace()`
otherwise, it takes `str.replace()` as replace of string, which takes minimum 2 arguments.

Comment: i'm getting the following error  ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' ```  if I try ```v=v.str.replace(',', '.')    ```

Comment: Check your data type of v by printing type(v). As I can infer, your v type is string. Is v required as a string or as a dataframe in your code? I'd suggest posting the entire code, so that it can be debugged

Answer (score -1):

Try these

`v=float(str.replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: i am getting the same error  ```TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)  ```